# InputStreams being GCed

Tags: java, garbage-collection, fileoutputstream

I know that if I do something like

```
copyFromInToOut(new FileInputStream(f1), new FileOutputStream(f2));
System.gc();
```

It will run the GC on those `FileInputStream`s, closing them. But if I do

```
copyFromInToOut(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f1)), new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f2));
System.gc();
```

Is there any danger that the FileOutputStream will be GCed before the BufferedOutputStream, not causing the buffer to flush?
I can't call flush, close, because that takes more steps than this. It would first involve declaring a bufferedinputstream, passing, then calling close. OR am I safe to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do the garbage collector's job?

Comment: Why are you reluctant to take "more steps than this"?

Comment: Do you have actual evidence that the garbage collector is A) collecting your stream while it is in use? and B) closing your stream?  Why would your streams even be eligible for GC -- did the thread doing the processing die, then perhaps the stream finalizer methods are getting called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't call `System.gc()` explicitly. Don't rely on finalizers to do anything. Especially if you don't understand how garbage collection works. Explicit garbage collection requests can be ignored, and finalizers might never run.

A well-written `copyFromInToOut` method for streams is likely to use its own buffer internally, so wrapping the output should be unnecessary.

Declare variables for the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, and invoke `close()` on each in a `finally` block:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f1);
try {
  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f2);
  try {
    copyFromInToOut(is, os);
    os.flush();
  } finally {
    os.close();
  }
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Comment: One minor comment.  Closing close() without guarding for the IOException in a finally block can cause issues if close() decides to throw an Exception when the try block already has.  (Or more generally, never allow an exception to be thrown by code in finally {} )

Comment: I wouldn't say that it "causes issues". What happens is that the result of the block changes from the exception that was thrown in the `try` block to the exception thrown by `close()`. Sometimes, this isn't desirable. In many cases, you just don't care. Java 7's ARM feature will make it easy to handle this in a consistent way.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>No InputStream implementation that I am aware with will `close()` for you when it is GCd.  You MUST `close()` the InputStream manually.</strike>

**EDIT**: Apparently FileInputStream does close() for you in a finalize method which I wasn't aware of, but see other answers for the reason why you shouldn't rely on this.

In both your examples above you must close both the Input and Output streams.  For the wrapped buffer case, and for any wrapped case, you should need only call `close()` on the outer-most `InputStream`, in this case `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: FileInputStream will close itself in its `finalized()` method

Comment: While you indeed should close() them yourself(you've no control over when an object is gc'ed, even if you call System.gc()), This is wrong. e.g. OpenJDK does .close() in its finalize() of a FileInputStream.

Comment: the first paragraph is incorrect.  FileInputStream (for example) *will* close a stream that is garbage collected.  But it is a really bad idea to rely on this; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

well it's interesting to analyze what's really happening when you do that, **just don't do that.**

always close your streams explicitly.

(to answer your question, yes, bytes in buffers may not have been flushed to file i/o streams when gc occurs and they are lost)

Answer (score 2):

Streams should be closed explicitly using the pattern shown in @erickson's answer.  Relying on finalization to close streams for you is a *really bad idea*:

1. Calling `System.gc()` is expensive, especially since (if it does anything) to is likely to trigger a full garbage collection.  That will cause *every reference in every reachable object* in your heap to be traced.
2. If you read the javadocs for `System.gc()` you will see that it is only a "hint" to the JVM to run the GC.  A JVM is free to ignore the hint ... which takes us to the next problem.
3. If you don't run the GC explicitly, it might be a long time until the GC runs.  And even then, there's no guarantee that finalizers are run immediately.

In the mean time:

- all open files stay open, possibly preventing other applications using them
- any unwritten data in the streams remains unwritten
- your java application might even run into problems opening other streams do to running out of file descriptor slots.

And there's one last problem with relying on finalization to deal with output streams.  If there is unflushed data in the stream when it is finalized, an output stream class will attempt to flush it.  But this is all happening on a JVM internal thread, not one of your application's threads.  So if the flush fails (e.g. because the file system is full), your application won't be able to catch the resulting exception, and therefore won't be able to report it ... or do anything to recover.

**EDIT**

Returning to the original question, it turns out that the BufferedOutputStream class does not override the default `Object.finalize()` method.  So that means that a BufferedOutputStrean is not flushed at all when it is garbage collected.  Any unwritten data in the buffer will be lost.

That's yet another reason for closing your streams explicitly.  Indeed, in this particular case, calling `System.gc()` is not just bad practice; it is also *likely* to lead to loss of data.